# Scala NullPointerException unless lazy

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception, lazy-sequences

```
  def fix[A, B](fn : Function2[Function1[A, B], A, B]) : Function1[A, B] =
    (x : A) => fn(fix(fn), x)

  lazy val fibs1 = fix[(Int, Int), Stream[Int]](
    (fn, a) => a._1 #:: fn((a._2, a._1 + a._2))
  )

  val fibs2 = fix[(Int, Int), Stream[Int]](
    (fn, a) => a._1 #:: fn((a._2, a._1 + a._2))
  )
```

While learning Scala I ran into a strange error. Why is it that `fibs1((1,1))` produces no error, while `fibs2((1, 1))` gives a null pointer exception?

EDIT:

This code was inside a App class. It seems like `val`s are not initialized until `instance.main(...)` is evaluated. I assume the implementation for `lazy val`s is different.

Comment: I don't have any NPE on fibs2 evaluation

Comment: same here, no NPE when I ran it on repl

Answer (score 0):

you are right. some val was not initialized, but since you make it a lazy val, it was only evaluated when needed, and at that time it was already initialized by some code you don't control